# win32com opens 2 processes

Tags: python, process, double, pyqt5

I used the QT-Designer to create a window with PyQt5. Everything works fine but when I run the frozen exe file, two processes get opened and only one is closing after pressing the X.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

If you need more info about the program just comment!

EDIT:
I found the place where the problem is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()

    # Run as admin
    import win32com.shell.shell as shell

    ASADMIN = 'asadmin'
    if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
        script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
        params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
        try:
            shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile=sys.executable, lpParameters=params)
        except:
            easygui.msgbox("You have to be admin.", "Error")
            sys.exit()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The "#Run as admin" part is opening the second process. But why? Maybe you can help me now ;)

EDIT:
I removed this part from the script. I'm now trying to modify the py2exe script so that it will force the user to be admin. This doesn't work:

```
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'includes': "sip, PyQt5.QtNetwork, PyQt5.QtWebKit, PyQt5.QtPrintSupport", 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': file,
                "icon_resources": [(1, "[Icon]")],
                'uac_info': "requireAdministrator"}],
    data_files = [('platforms', [
        'C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll'
        ])],
)
```

Does someone know how to force the user to be admin?

Comment: Always provide a working example of your code, context, errors you may be getting, screenshots if possible - any extra details that can let people help you better. A minimum verifiable code. Without that there is no way anyone can help.

Comment: @kartikg3 I've added some code. Maybe the QWebView is opening a second process?

Comment: @crey4fun what kartikg3 meant by "minimum verifiable code" is this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It's the smallest possible program that someone else can *actually run*, but still produces the problem. Making this example can, in itself, help you find the problem: e.g., if you take the QWebView and the problem stops? Now you know it's there.

Comment: @Lack I found the root of the problem. It's in the run as admin part. But what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. It looks like py2exe for Python 3 can't force the user to be admin. I've added some code to the py2exe program to get this working:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
import easygui

manifest = '''
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
       <asmv3:trustInfo xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
         <asmv3:security>
           <asmv3:requestedPrivileges>
             <asmv3:requestedExecutionLevel
               level="requireAdministrator"
               uiAccess="false" />
           </asmv3:requestedPrivileges>
         </asmv3:security>
       </asmv3:trustInfo>
     </assembly>
'''

file = easygui.fileopenbox("Script")

sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'includes': "sip, PyQt5.QtNetwork, PyQt5.QtWebKit, PyQt5.QtPrintSupport", 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': file,
                "icon_resources": [(1, "[Icon]")],
                'other_resources':[(24, 1, manifest)]}],
    data_files = [('platforms', [
        'C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll'
        ])],
)
```